# Correct Xpath for on scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to get the data only from `category` using Xpath

Page link: https://onepagelove.com/3wcc

This is my output:

```
 ['Digital Product', ',', 'Finance', ',', 'Landing Page', ',', 'Thaleah Fat', ',', '23 Feb 2022 by', 'Rob Hope']}
```

This is an example of the data in the webpage:

[image]

This is my code:

```
from scrapy.http import Request
import scrapy
class PushpaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'pushpa'
    
    start_urls = ['https://onepagelove.com/inspiration']
    

    def parse(self, response):
        books = response.xpath("//div[@class='thumb-image']//a//@href").extract()
        for book in books:
            absolute_url = response.urljoin(book)
            yield Request(absolute_url, callback=self.parse_book)

    def parse_book(self, response):
        coordinate = response.xpath("//div[@class='inspo-links']//span[2]//text()").getall()
        coordinate = [i.strip() for i in coordinate]
        # remove empty strings:s
        coordinate = [i for i in coordinate if i]
        yield{
            'category':coordinate
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website has multiple `inspo-links` inside the header, thus you are extracting from many different types of data.

Xpath version:

```
def parse_book(self, response):
    xpath_coordinate = response.xpath(
        "//span[@class='link-list']")[1].xpath("a/text()").extract()
    yield {
        'category': xpath_coordinate
    }
```

CSS version:

```
def parse_book(self, response):
    content = response.css('div.review-content')
    coordinate = header.css("span.link-list")[1].css("a::text").extract()
    yield {
        'category': coordinate
    }
```

This snippet here will provide you only the categories.

On your image example, it would give you ["Experimental", "Informational"]

Note: On your main method you are getting an extra link for something that is not a book and doesn't have categories, scrapy automatically handles the errors, so you still get the complete output.

Here is an Xpath example that brings all 3 types of data from the image:

```
def parse_book(self, response):
    xpath_coordinate = response.xpath(
        "//span[@class='link-list']")
    features = xpath_coordinate[0].xpath("a/text()").extract()
    category = xpath_coordinate[1].xpath("a/text()").extract()
    typeface = xpath_coordinate[2].xpath("a/text()").extract()
    yield {
        'feature': features,
        'category': category,
        'typeface': typeface
    }
```

Comment: if I want to get the data from `typeface` what is xpath for it?

Comment: @AmenAziz I added a snippet for you with the 3 data types at the end of the answer, hope it helps!